# Could not autowire. No beans of ... type found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

can you help me solve why i can't autowire a class??
class UserDaoImpl:

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM user").list();
    }

}
```

i want this class autowire into other class:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao; //here is the error

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {

    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    String message = "This should be a list of users";

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public ModelAndView showMessage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("user");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

where can be the problem? should i show you more files? thanks.
EDIT: ok so this is my session-factory.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/****</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">****</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">****</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

 </beans>
```

-class User is simple POJO which is mapped with hibernate. And maybe web.xml can help us :)

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

mvc-servlet-dispatcher.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and i don't have any applicationContext.xml file, maybe this can be the problem, can you help me with that?
I'm adding a screenshot of my project and problem: http://screenshot.cz/75QVH/

Comment: Yes, of course, show us your configuration. Why do you expect one to be autowired into the other?

Comment: And show the actual exception.

Comment: Show us your `applicationContext.xml` file and `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

Comment: And the package names for these classes. I suspect your component scanning.

Comment: I added the a screenshot with package names..

Answer (score 5):

Your `@Repository` is not being picked up (scanned) by `<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />` going by what you are showing us. But we would need to see the packages for each class. Spring depend on you to tell it what packages to look in for your `@Service`, `@Controller`, `@Repository` and `@Component`.

Have a look at how component scanning works in spring.

Comment: Just saw your package structure, you should clean this up and have com.foo.web, com.foo.service etc and then have your `<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />` set to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo" />` and it should pick up your Repository classes.

Comment: Yes i found it too, thanks, error dissapeared, but i'm still getting exceptions which starts with:  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is...

Comment: Need to see your controller as that is now where your problem is. Also the exception stack trace would help.

Comment: my controller is very simple, just to show a message, because actually my database is empty and i just want to set up base application, but i added it to my post, and here's full stack trace: http://pastebin.com/tjfR1vMJ

Comment: Looks like the org.hibernate.SessionFactory bean is missing. So it looks like the session-factory.xml is NOT being read. You can do this a couple of ways, one is to import session-factory.xml in the mvc-servlet-dispatcher.xml or just copy sessionFactory bean into the mvc-servlet-dispatcher.xml file

Comment: i imported content of session-factory.xml into that xml file, but still tones of errors, im desperated :/ stack trace here... http://pastebin.com/FmHEWfw9

Comment: Looks like you have a problem connecting to your Postgres database, in the log you are getting "PSQLException: The connection attempt failed" do you have Postgres running and can you connect to it using pgAdmin with the setting you have defined in the sessionFactory above?

Comment: Oh my god it seems the problem was on first error = i was starting 64 bit tomcat on 32 bit machine, its solved probably, thanks so much for help, but i still don't get it why autowiring wasn't working only for session factory..

Answer (score -1):

Do not print @Autowired before print bean. otherwise，the No beans of … type found will occur

`@Autowired
private ProjectRepository projectRepository;`